# Accessing $_SESSION from outside of Joomla

Tags: php, session, joomla

I used Joomla 1.5 for a site that I developed for a gaming company.  Part of the site consists of a character generater for the game that they developed.  The issue is that users want to be able to print the character sheets off, without having the Joomla template surrounding it.

As for the specifics, I have the directphp extension installed, and the entire generator is written in PHP (with a little JavaScript to handle things that PHP can't).  As the generator spans several dozen page calls, it made sense to store everything in $_SESSION.  All of this works correctly.  In an attempt to make the final sheet printer friendly, I tried redirecting the user to a page outside of Joomla (though on the same server, and even within the same folder) but I cannot access the $_SESSION data from this new page.

I have seen several posts (a few on this site) that point to loading the Joomla Framework and accessing it that way, which I have tried, but the data that I was looking for does not appear to be contained there.  Has anyone come across this problem before, or know how to get to that data?

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of the non-Joomla script?

Comment: I do.  I have also confirmed that the session_id() values are different by checking both scripts, and I have tried setting the id on the non-Joomla script to match the Joomla script to no avail.

Comment: And when you `print_r($_SESSION)`, you get nothing? Does Joomla have it's own custom SESSION handling (maybe in a database)?

Comment: yes `print_r($_SESSION)` results in only Array().  I'm pretty sure that Joomla handles sessions differently, which is why everyone was saying to load the Framework and call it that way, which isn't showing me what I'm looking for unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this WAY harder than it needs to be. You don't have to write any additional code to accomplish what you are trying to do. In order to print our the component output without all of the Joomla template, you just append `?tmpl=component` to your URLs and Joomla will display only to component output without any of the template. If you want to give it a custom stylesheet or anything special, you can also add in a template override by adding a file named component.php in your template folder.

In order to control the CSS per page, you can add Page Class Suffixes in the menu items. Then add this code to index.php so you can use them.

Somewhere in the head add this:

```
$menu = &JSite::getMenu();
$active = $menu->getActive();
$pageclass = "";
if (is_object( $active )) :
    $params = new JParameter( $active->params );
    $pageclass = trim($params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' ));
endif;
```

Replace your body tag with this:

```
<body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? $pageclass : 'default'; ?>">
```

Any page that you do not specific a Page Class Suffix for will use `default` as the body ID, any that you do will use what ever you specify.

Comment: HA!  Isn't the first time that I made something way more complicated than it had to be, and it certainly won't be the last.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Someone else created the template for this site, and used Artisteer to do it.  There is already a component.php file, and something in the site's CSS is screwing up the tables.  I don't suppose that there's a way to make this section of the page ignore inherited CSS is there?

Comment: You can control the CSS per page by adding a page class suffix in the menu item under the Parameters (System) options. You will probably need to add some code to the template so it adds the suffix to the body tag, then you can do what ever you like to the page simply bu using that selector to specific the CSS. I'll add the code to the answer.